# ASP.NET Core 3.0 not routing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.0

I have recently upgraded an existing **ASP.NET Core** *2.2* web app to *3.0*. Everything now compiles. However when I go to run the application I am greeted with a directory listing instead of the login page.

[image]

Our app uses **Razor** pages as opposed to full blown MVC. Reading around the many changes in **ASP.NET Core** 3.0 I can see that the way in which routing is implemented has changed substantially.

Previously in the **ConfigureServices** we had the following.

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => { options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); });
```

And in the **Configure** method we had this.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

This all worked fine. What changes are needed to get the app to route correctly now that we have upgraded to **ASP.NET Core** 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the default `controller` on the default route. For sample:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
```

I am not sure if your default controller should be `Home` but define it on the `template` and it will work when the user with an empty route access the applicaton.

Comment: I've tried that but it hasn't solved the problem. Is this the only way to define the default controller?

Comment: It works however when you place the line of code at the top of the function :)

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Core 3 & .Net Core 3.1 you have to delete 
`services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => { options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); });` and
`services.AddMvc();` from `ConfigureServices`:

Then add `services.AddRazorPages();`

In  `Configure` add:

`app.UseRouting();`

`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());`

`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });`

Finally your code will be like this:

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddRazorPages();
            }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                                             {
                                               endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", " 
                                               {controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                                              });                 
            }
    }
```

To get more information take a look at [Microsof documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Let me try that and get back. Thanks.

Comment: @DomBurf I hope that my answer helped you to solve the problem :)